Task Scheduler shows completed tasks as still running
I have seen these 3 tasks complete yet Task Scheduler still shows them as running even after refresh and closing and reopening.
Why do you make this hard for people trying to help by not posting EVERYONE'S images?
Task Scheduler showing the task as still running.
Task Manager Deluxe showing no running tasks for the backup program
I tried refreshing and closing and reopening Task Scheduler.
I'd ezxpect they should be done, completed.

This is a os issue and not a programming issue.

I always wondered why MS had that weird Stop Task if it runs for more than X hours as a default.  They didn't know how to fix the code.  But if I set that and some task is on a resource wait does that count as time?  I would expect it would but then the setting becomes superfulous.
